# How to access history object outside <Route /> in React Router v4

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I have this following code:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'


const Routes = () => (
  <Router basename="/blog">
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
      <Route path="/article/:id" component={ArticleView}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

I can access history or match via props in the Main and ArticleView component. But I cannot access it in the `<Header />`. Is there a way to get the history object in the Header component?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC for this.

Where your Header component is defined, wrapping the export in a withRouter invocation like below will give your Header component access to match, location, and history

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

class Header extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
  render () {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return <h2>The Header</h2>
  }
}

export default withRouter(Header)
```

Comment: I think withRouter only works if the component is part of <Route />. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: If the component is part of <Route />, there should be no need to use withRouter then. Unless I'm confused.

Comment: Hey @Tayler, you're confused haha. My <Header /> is not part of a <Route />. It is inside <Router /> but not <Route />. So I can't access those props from there.

Comment: Tyler's answer is correct.  You can access to history, match or location by two ways:

1. By `withRouter` wrapper
2. By passing Header to Route: `<Route component={Header} />`

Comment: Yeah. That's the entire point of withRouter. Did you try out the code I gave you?

Comment: @SergeyReutskiy I can't pass Header to the Route because it's common between different routes and I don't want it to be rendered again and again.
I tried wrapping the header using withRouter HOC. It still says PropTypes history is required but the value is undefined.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @TylerMcGinnis

Comment: When I try to use "withRouter" as shown here I get the error, `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`

Comment: @Jim maybe you haven't Routes at all? I mean at least single Route at the top level of components' tree should exist.

Comment: Also, make sure that your main app is encapsulated by `<BrowserRouter>`