# Not able to use WithRouter of react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am new to the react js. Here I am trying to use the `withrouter` to get the info of my location.

SO, I have following structure.

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
 <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Main />
        </div>
      </Provider>
```

**Main.js**

```
return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          {this.props.isFetching && <Loading />}
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/create-job" component={NewJob} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/user-jobs" component={JobList} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Now, I am trying to use the withRouter in the `Header.js`. which is not a part of the `Router`. SO,

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {  logout  })(Header));
```

I tried using this way. So, it is giving me the following error.

```
You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
```

What is it that I am doing wrong over here ?

Comment: you need to wrap `Header` component with `<Router/>` component

Comment: No but that is the purpose of the withrouter

Comment: no, it's not . its purpose is to pass props like `match` to the component which are  not defined as / in `Route` component

Answer (score 1):

You're rendering the `Header` component (which uses `withRouter`) outside the `Router` component. You need to make sure that all the `Route`s and the components using `withRouter` need to be a child of `Router`, at some level in the hierarchy.

In your case, maybe wrap the `div` in the `App` with the `Router`?

**Details from source**

The error is generated [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/9d278b4b110f38479725fe5a1104990c2f3e76c2/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L22) when `Route` doesn't get passed a `context` from its [provider](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/9d278b4b110f38479725fe5a1104990c2f3e76c2/packages/react-router/modules/Router.js#L55). And, [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/9d278b4b110f38479725fe5a1104990c2f3e76c2/packages/react-router/modules/withRouter.js#L15) is just a wrapper over `Route`. The only time the context is not available is when the `Route` is not nested inside a `Router` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that withRouter props get blocked by PureComponent check, put it after connect:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {  logout  })(withRouter(Header));
```

See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#important-note

Personally I prefer to have my providers in one place in index.js not App.js, your whole app should be wrapped in Router, not a part of App.js:

```
const WrappedApp = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(WrappedApp, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `<Header>` component inside `<Router>` component, otherwise it doesn't work as the error says.

Comment: Yes, but that is the purpose of the withRouter I guess

Comment: The purpose of withRouter is to get the Router from a parent element. If there's no parent Router element, then there's nothing to get.

Comment: @GaneshKaspate Nope, the purpose of `withRouter` is that whenever you don't have a component handled by `<Route>` (those are LandingPage, NewJob etc. in your example), then you can decorate it with `withRouter` and you'll get access to history and other Router props. I suggest you to move `<Router>`to `App.js` instead of `<div>` ...`withRouter` works only if the component is somewhere inside the `<Router>`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do 2 things, inject the state in the Header, and inject routing information in Header.
If you are outside of the `<Router/>` component you will not be able to use withRouter(, simply because you will not have any match props to link to your compoonent.

What you need to do is to create something called layouts.... and use the layouts in the page definition like this.

Lets say you have this Route `<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingPageContainer} />`
Now inside the LandingPage you need to do something like

```
landingPageContainer.js
render() {
   return (
    <SimpleLayout header={<Header ...this.props/> footer={<Footer ...this.props/>}>
       <LandingPageDummyPage ...this.props/>
    <SimpleLayout/>
   );
}
export default connect(withRouter(LandingPageContainer);
```

this will copy all the props passed to the Simple Layout to your LandingPageLayout, header and footer

```
simpleLayout.js
render() {
   return (
    <div>{this.props.header} </div>
    <div>{this.props.children} </div>
    <div{this.props.footer} </div>
   );
}

export withRouter(SimpleLayout);

advice . read the router documentation and try to understand whats the purpose if it... you didn`t quite get it :) ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594804/how-to-access-history-object-outside-route-in-react-router-v4