# How to access BrowserRouter history outside of BrowserRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Below is my code snippet simplified. (using react-router-v5)
My question is how to get access to BrowserRouter's history in the logout_Handler(), given that I am "outside" BrowserRouter?

I've seen this answer [How to access history object outside <Route /> in React Router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594804/how-to-access-history-object-outside-route-in-react-router-v4)
, but there is also a comment which applies to my case:
"When I try to use "withRouter" as shown here I get the error

> You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

which is exactly what I get, if I try to use withRouter at the App.js level.

```
// App.js

function App(props) {

    const logout_Handler = (e) => {

        localStorage.removeItem("app-tokenObj");

        // how to get the history from BrowserRouter to redirect?!
        //history.push("/login") ?? NO IDEA ??

    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <nav>
                <h3>My Supa Dupa App</h3>

                <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
                <Link to="/admin">Admin Page</Link>
                <button type="button" onClick={logout_Handler}>Logout</button>
            </nav>
            
            <hr/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/link1" component={Comp1} />
                <Route path="/link2" component={Comp1} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            </Switch>

        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access parts of a routing context in the `App` component then the router providing the context needs to be higher in the ReactTree. The solution is simple. Move `BrowserRouter` higher than `App` in your apps code. Wrapping `App` in the `BrowserRouter` would be sufficient enough for this.

Example index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  ...
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  ...,
  root,
);
```

App

The `App` component now has a routing context available. While you *could* use the `withRouter` Higher Order Component, using the [`useHistory`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook would be simpler.

```
import { Link, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function App(props) {
  const history = useHistory();

  const logout_Handler = (e) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("app-tokenObj");
    history.push("/login");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <h3>My Supa Dupa App</h3>

        <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
        <Link to="/admin">Admin Page</Link>
        <button type="button" onClick={logout_Handler}>Logout</button>
      </nav>
            
      <hr/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/link1" component={Comp1} />
        <Route path="/link2" component={Comp1} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I first ran into this issue with Class Components (pre React 16.8 when Hooks were not around), in that case useHistory was not available, but moving BrowserRouter up the tree would work !

Comment: Also ""you could use the withRouter HOC" are you sure? please try it yourself and see if you get an error, as I alluded to in my question !

Comment: @joedotnot Sorry, I meant you could use the `withRouter` HOC instead of using the `useHistory` hook to have `history` injected as a prop. The router still needs to be lifted above `App` to provide a routing context for the `withRouter` HOC to access.

Answer (score 0):

#for move one folder previous:

history.push("/../login")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).